# Stretch image to fit boundary coordinates in TileMill

Tags: tilemill, mapbox

I would like to add an image as a layer to a Tile Mill map by specifying the coordinates. Is this possible? If so, how would I do this?

I've seen [this](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/how-to-add-images-maps-tilemill-svg-support/) being done, where an image is set to certain coordinates, but I would like to stretch an image to fit to two corner coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at Mapbox's [Working with Geotiffs](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/) guide. Even if your image is not a geotiff, something like that should work--[gdal supports many formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html). The trick might be figuring out what to use as the source projection.